# What happens if you have the data layer being populated within the google tagmanager snippet?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A client has the following implementation of the GTM snippet. So far I have only seen implementations where the datalayer is being populated by using a datalayer push before the GTM snippet is being loaded. Is there a good argument to implement the GTM snippet like this?

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xxxxxxxx" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
    dataLayer = [{"automaticLogin":"true","loginSuccess":true,"pageName":"homepage","pagetype":"home","customerBaskedValue":xxxxx,"customerId":"xxxxxxx","sitePage":"d","isOptIn":true,"sessionId":"xxxxxxxxx","customerGender":"man","customerBirthDate":"1989-09-21T00:00:00","customerZip":"xxxxx","customerCity":"xxxxx","customerState":"Nederland","customerEmailID":"xxxx","orderNewCustomer":false,"customerLastMarketingChannel":null,"sessionDevice":"desktop","isFirstVisit":false}];

    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });

        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],   
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';

        j.async = true; j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-xxxx');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is absolutely fine and sometimes encouraged. The benefit of pushing things onto the dataLayer before the container code executes is that these values will be available to GTM as soon as the `gtm.js` event is fired. The `gtm.js` event is often used as a trigger (e.g. in the built in All Pages trigger). So when you want certain values to be passed to a tag thag has the All Pages trigger assigned to it, you must make sure that the values are pushed onto the dataLayer *before* the container code executes.

Comment: thanks for your answer! The client has  an ecommerce website with sometimes very long product lists. These lists are being send in batches and are also being set in the data layer of the GTM snippet. I was thinking that this might cause a delay of the firing of the GTM snippet. Is that possible? For some pages with very long product lists the impression events are being measured, but the pageview is not being set. Can this also be related or do I have the search in an other direction?

Comment: how long are we talking? Pushing data onto the dataLayer is a pretty low latency operation (the dataLayer is just a JavaScript array) so I doubt this is what's causing the missing pageviews.

Comment: I checked with BigQuery and I see that the lists maximum list position is 96. 

What I also see is that in a lot of sessions the first isn't a pageview type, but an event. I know this causes a high bouncerate in Google Analytics if you break this down by page, but I don't know if this also effects the marketing channel measurement.